# Proving that nth derivate of $x e^{-x}$ is $(-1)^n (e^{-x})(x-n)$ by induction.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, induction

I'm quite stuck on this. How would you prove that the $n^{th}$ derivative of $x e^{-x}$ if the $(-1)^n (e^{-x})(x-n)$ by induction?

I did:

$\frac{d}{dx}(x e^{-x})=(e^{-x}) - x(e^{-x})$

Now I have no idea how to proceed and prove this by induction. I would really appreciate if anyone could guide me. A clear answer would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You meant $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}$, I suppose?

Comment: @DanielFischer Yep. Let me edit

Comment: Start with verifying the base case ($n = 0$). Then $$\frac{d^{n+1}}{dx^{n+1}} (xe^{-x}) = \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(xe^{-x})\right),$$ use the induction hypothesis to replace the contents of the big parenthesis, differentiate, gather terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Carrying out a proof by induction usually (probably always?) involves three steps:

1. The base step: Proof the assumption for a specific $n$. That is what you already did, you showed that the assumption holds for $n=1$. You have no choice but to simply try it out.
2. Induction step: now you try to show, that, if the assumption holds for a given $n$, it is also valid for the successor of $n$, namely $n+1$. Let me demonstrate:
   You assume (and write down on your scrap sheet), that the relationship
   \begin{eqnarray}
   \frac{d^{n}}{dx^{n}}(xe^{-x})&=&(-1)^{n}(e^{-x})(x-n)
   \end{eqnarray}
   holds for a given, but yet unknown $n$. "You assume" means, that for the moment you don't proof it, but rather accept the idea that there might be such a $n$. The question is: Does it also work for $n+1$? Again, you find this out by trying. You want to know what the $(n+1)$th derivative is, so just try it out:
   \begin{eqnarray}
   \frac{d^{n+1}}{dx^{n+1}}(xe^{-x})&=&\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{d^{n}}{dx^{n}}(xe^{-x})\right)\\
   &=& \frac{d}{dx}\left((-1)^{n}(e^{-x})(x-n)\right)\\
   &=& (-1)^n(-1)(e^{-x})(x-n)+(-1)^n(e^{-x}),
   \end{eqnarray}
   by application of chain rule. Now, what you obviously need is the result:
   \begin{eqnarray}
   \frac{d^{n+1}}{dx^{n+1}}(xe^{-x})=(-1)^{n+1}(e^{-x})(x-(n+1)).
   \end{eqnarray}
   It means you have to manipulate the result of your differentiation in a way that it resembles this one:
   \begin{eqnarray}
   \frac{d^{n+1}}{dx^{n+1}}(xe^{-x})&=& (-1)^n(-1)(e^{-x})(x-n)+(-1)^n(e^{-x})\\
   &=& (-1)^{n+1}(e^{-x})(x-n)+(-1)^{n+1}(-1)(e^{-x}) \quad\text{because $(-1)(-1)=1$}\\
   &=& (-1)^{n+1}(e^{-x})\left(x-n-1\right)\quad\text{by factoring out $(-1)^{n+1}(e^{-x})$}\\
   &=& (-1)^{n+1}(e^{-x})(x-(n+1)).
   \end{eqnarray}
3. The last step is a rather formal one, but maybe the intelectually most demanding. You have to bring your two results together. In the induction step you showed, that, if there is any $n$ for which the assumption holds, then it also holds for $n+1$. In your base step you showed indeed, that it holds for $n=1$. With the induction step it follows that it is also valid for $n+1=2$. If you set $k=n+1$ you see that it is also valid for $k+1=n+2=3$, and so on. Thus, the assumption is valid for *any* $n$, because you can reach any be adding $1$ often enough.

According to your task it may be neccessary to show, that it also holds for $n=0$. This is the general scheme to solve such problems. The second step is the most difficult. You should write down what you expect at the end (as I did) and then simply try different algebraic manipulations until you reach the goal. With some practice you get more skilled in that.

Hope that helped you. Kind regards,

Christoph

Comment: This is perfect. I didn't expect to get such a good explanation. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: As a reply to 'always?', note that sometimes for step $1$ you will prove that the claim is true for *all n up to* $n$, then prove it for $n+1$ (as opposed to just for $n$). Also, you may occasionally assume it for $n,n-1$ and $n-2$ (for example), then prove it for $n+1$.